# Rendering ocean scene, but ends up as a cube

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, ocean-simulation

I am new to blender, and I am trying to render my animated ocean scene. However, when I render only the cube I started with is visible, not the ocean. And the cube does not show in my viewport. Any suggestions on what I can do to render my ocean animation?

Comment: Your question lacks the information to be able to help you. Please consider adding more details and upload your scene, or a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example  to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add the generated link to your question by using the "edit" button

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the ocean modifier, then it would be best to use a plane not a cube. Also, you need to subdivide the plane before you add the modifier. You can do this by adding a subdivision surface modifier, or subdividing in edit mode. You also may need to keyframe the ocean modifier, if you have not done so.